# Why does not $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ converge uniformly to $0$ on $(-1,1)$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

If I have understood it correctly; First, let $Q_n = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Then,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} || Q_n -0|| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in (-1,1)}|Q_n|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in (-1,1)} \dfrac{|x^{n+1}|}{|1-x|} \qquad \qquad (\ast)$$

For the latter RHS: no matter the value of $n \geq 1$ (just particularly as I am working with sequences), the supremum will always be $\infty$ as,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \dfrac{\text{"1"}}{\text{"0"}} \rightarrow +\infty$$

as no matter what $n$, it will always be infinity. Even less, it is not equal to $0$ in $(\ast)$ as the uniform convergence requires.

Edit: Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it's sufficient.

Comment: Another way is by noting that for any $n\geq 2$, $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{( - 1,1)} \frac{{\left| x \right|^{n + 1} }}{{\left| {1 - x} \right|}} \ge \frac{{\left| {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right|^{n + 1} }}{{\left| {1 - \left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right|}} \ge \frac{n}{8}.
$$

Comment: Someone nerfed this problem by putting that division by $1-x$ in it. $x^n$ on $(0,1)$ is the archtypical example of a sequence of functions that converges pointwise, but not uniformly..